# How to set up DataFrame to refresh itself after changes to underlying database table?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to take a look if spark has some capability to Refresh the DataFrame-RDD to reflect changes to the underlying table from which DataFrame RDD is loaded.

E.g.

1. DataFrame loaded from a Table A.
2. Table A Changes
3. Will DataFrame RDD reflect the change to the table A now

If Spark does not provide such option then do I have to maintain some kind of Cached Table for that via ehCache or MemCache etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark RDD si designed to be immutable, so I think your desire breaks the root idea of Spark RDD, so properly no.

Second thought your idea is kind of difficult to achieve, as the calculation process can took a long time, while if the source is changed and your idea is true, how can it handle the gap in run-time? not mentioning the same RDD can be shared by multiple process.